# How to to get the values of a HTML code into variables in Colab

Tags: html, variables, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use a HTML code inside google Colab to get user location. I got the location displayed using this code, but I could not save latitude and longitude into variables. I can get the values displayed, but do not know how to store them into variables. Could someone help me get the values stored into lat and long?

```
from Ipython.display import HTML
HTML(
'''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
}
getLocation()
</script>
</body>
</html>
''')

display(IPython.display.HTML(html_code))
```

Comment: `window.lat = position.coords.latitude`
`window.long = position.coords.longitude`

Is this what your looking for ?

Comment: @aemonge Thanks for answering! What I mean is something like: user_long = (the value of longitude), user_lat = (the value of latitude). So I could use those directly into another function.